# Add value to each element in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, list, kotlin

How to add a value to each integer value to array/list. I searched but didn't find any solution in kotlin.

I tried in this way but it is showing error..

```
fun main() {
 val arrayNum = arrayOf(2,3,9)
 val newArrayNum = arrayNum.foreach { it ->
     it += 2
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `map` to create a new list with your new elements and then transform it back to an array:

```
val newArrayNum = arrayNum.map { it + 2 }.toTypedArray()
```

This is the less performant solution since it will create a new `ArrayList` under the hood and a new array.

To avoid the creation of the `ArrayList` you can do:

```
val newArrayNum = IntArray(arrayNum.size) { index ->
    arrayNum[index] + 2
}
```

To modify the content of the original array (without creating new arrays or `ArrayList`) you can do:

```
arrayNum.forEachIndexed { index, value ->
    arrayNum[index] = value + 2
}
```

Comment: Instead of the last example, `forEachIndexed` would be more "Kotlin way"

arrayNum.forEachIndexed { index, value ->
  arrayNum[index] = value + 2
}

Comment: In the second also: why create an array of 0s and then set element by element instead of initializing it to correct values immediately?

Answer (score 1):

```
 val newArrayNum = arrayNum.map { it + 2  }
```